# Accessing the class in which my method is in java

Tags: java, class

I have a class called Game and a button in it with the following code

```
public Game(){
    (some code..)
    btn_start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                               (some code..)
                    timer_task = new MyTask();
                               (some code..)
                }
            });
        }
}
```

My problem is that MyTask requires an object of type "Game" (for various reason).
How can i send to MyTask() the class that my actionListener method is in?
Is there such a thing in Java?

I tried using `.this` but it says that it refers to the `ActionListener`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `Game.this` instead

This basically tells Java to use the outter class reference of `this` instead

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider having a private method in your class `Game` to create `MyTask`. Something like

```
public void someMethod()
{
    ...
    btn_start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            handleStart();
        }
    });
    ...
}

private void handleStart()
{
    (some code..)
    timer_task = new MyTask(this);
    (some code..)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. That's what i did at first but i needed to access some property from that private class in other classes so i ended up making it public.

Comment: yes, depending on your situation. The pattern is to make these handler methods private at first, and then make them public if you need to call them by other external processes than an event listener (or other external event listeners). In short, it is a reusable pattern any way. The principle lies into making event listener methods as short as possible to favour reusable code patterns :) Though I have to admit `Game.this` may be appealing, use it wisely!